# Folder Encryption Not Working (Demo Included)

Tags: java, encryption, zip, zip4j

This simple folder encryption/compression fails. The folder only contains a child folder and text file, yet encryption returns false. Any idea why?

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.AesKeyStrength;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.CompressionLevel;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.CompressionMethod;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.EncryptionMethod;
import java.io.File;

public class Demo_ZipEncryptFolderOnly {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ZipException {
        ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
        zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        zipParameters.setCompressionMethod(CompressionMethod.DEFLATE);
        zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(CompressionLevel.NORMAL);
        zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES);
        zipParameters.setAesKeyStrength(AesKeyStrength.KEY_STRENGTH_256);
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Folder.zip", "password".toCharArray());
        zipFile.addFolder(new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Folder"));
        System.out.println("Encrypted: "+zipFile.isEncrypted());
    }
}
```

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Folder to Encrypt:**

[image: Folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass `zipParameters` as second parameter in the `zipFile.addFolder()` call. If this is fixed, it works (s. also the [*zip4j* docs](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j#creating-a-password-protected-zip-file--adding-files-to-an-existing-zip-with-password-protection)):

```
zipFile.addFolder(new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Folder"), zipParameters);
```